# ndk build library outside main project source tree

Tags: android-ndk

I wants to build a 3rd party library avahi using ndk. avahi has android port already (with valid Android.mk).

What I have done: 
I have successfully created a project and copied all the source code in to jni/ folder and run ndk-build. It builds libavahi.so

What I wants to do:
Instead of copying all the source code into jni/ folder, I'd like to store it in a folder outside project source tree. What shall I do? I have looked into NDK DOCUMENTATION/Import Module but nothing is similar to my case.

Newbie in ndk, and any suggestion is welcomed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right, this is not the case of *Import Module*. The way you reference the **avihi** library from your native code will still be as **LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES** (see NDK sample **[module-exports](http://mirror.yongbok.net/pub/pub/linux/android/repository/development/ndk/samples/module-exports/)**). But in your `jni/Android.mk` file, you may use `include` command to another file. This command is very similar to `#include` statement in **C**. This file needs not to be inside your project tree. Taking the same sample, here is how it can work:

Original [Android.mk from samples/module-exports/jni](http://mirror.yongbok.net/pub/pub/linux/android/repository/development/ndk/samples/module-exports/jni/Android.mk):

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := foo
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := foo/foo.c
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DFOO=2
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/foo
LOCAL_EXPORT_CFLAGS := -DFOO=1
LOCAL_EXPORT_LDLIBS := -llog
include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := bar
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := bar/bar.c
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/bar
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := foo
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := zoo
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := zoo/zoo.c
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := bar
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

The changed file will look as follows:

```
ZOO_LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include ~/projects/bar/jni/Android.mk
LOCAL_PATH := $(ZOO_LOCAL_PATH)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := zoo
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := zoo/zoo.c
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := bar
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

And the ***external*** bar/jni/Android.mk as follows:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := foo
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := foo/foo.c
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DFOO=2
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/foo
LOCAL_EXPORT_CFLAGS := -DFOO=1
LOCAL_EXPORT_LDLIBS := -llog
include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := bar
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := bar/bar.c
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/bar
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := foo
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Now, both files bar.c and foo.c may be kept outside the tree of the zoo project!